# Distance between sets of $\mathbb {R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Distance between sets of $\mathbb {R^n}$.

Definition: Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$. We define the distance $d(A, B)$ between the sets $A$ and $B$, as:

$d(A, B)= \inf$ {$|x-y|: x \in A, y \in B$}

Now consider the sets $A = ${$(x, 0): x \in \mathbb{R}$} and $B=$ { $(x, 1/x): x >0$}, which are disjoint. Show that $d (A, B) = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>0$, the distance between the points $p=(x,0)$ and $q=(x,1/x)$ is exactly $|p-q|=1/x$. Thus
$$d(A,B)=\inf\{|p-q|:p\in A, q\in B\}\le\inf\{1/x:x>0\}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=0$$

Comment: Your second "$=$" sign should be "$\le$".

Comment: @LeeMosher like that?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By convergence of $\frac{1}{x}\to 0$ when $x$ to infinity, exists $A>0$ such that for $x>0, |x|>A$ implies $\frac{1}{x}<\varepsilon$. By these argument, choosing one  $x$ with  the property above, $d(A,B)\leq |(x,0)-(x,1/x)|=|(0,1/x)|=1/x<\varepsilon$. By arbitrariety of $\varepsilon $, we  can conclude that $d(A,B)=0$.